# How to make an Eclipse launch configuration that calls ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I build my Eclipse project from ANT. I would also like to use ANT to run it as well. Clicking `build.xml` every time is somewhat annoying. More importantly, I have multiple different ways in which I like to launch it from ant (test, release, etc.).

Is there a way I can use ANT for a launch configuration. The other advantage here is that my launch configuration would not depend on Eclipse, so I could use ant from the command line if I wish, with the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using ant from Eclipse you can use the default shortcut of `ALT+SHIFT+X,Q` to launch the default build configuration for that project.

If you have multiple build configurations that you created from the **Run As** menu then it will ask you to select one, or it does in Helios.

Also it is easy to [run ant from the command line](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html).

I personally also use the EasyShell plugin to be able to quickly launch cmd/cygwin in the project directory from directly in eclipse.

Comment: This answer led me to find out that I can configure an "external tools configuration" instead of a "run configurations". I can add it to my favorites and it appears not in the "play" button, but the "play" button with a toolbox (for the lack of better words).

Comment: Ah yes, Ant and Maven go in there; JUnit, Java, JBoss, etc., go in the Run and Debug drop downs. I'm a keyboard shortcut kind of guy so don't use those much!

Comment: Yes, and I am too...but this is a collaborative project and unfortunately not every one else is. :P